Sphinx does not find value in json property
I apologize in advance if I don't understand something, this is the first time I've encountered a sphinx.
I have such row in my index
|    id     | content_id | account_id | is_deleted | filters|
| 356435435 | 232423532  |  24234325  |     0      | {"id":356435435,"account_id":232423532,"name":"test","customs":{"48467277":5436789765432456.000000,"48467755":"texttexttext"}} |

filters is JSON string, where i store some data.
When I'm making such request I get 0 rows
SELECT * FROM index_name WHERE account_id = 356435435 AND is_deleted = 0 AND MATCH('( @account_id_key =356435435 ) @!account_id_key 5436789765432456');

And I don't get, why it works like that. But if I make such request, I get my row.
SELECT * FROM index_name WHERE account_id = 356435435 AND is_deleted = 0 AND MATCH('( @account_id_key =356435435 ) @!account_id_key 89765432');

I also tried making
@!account_id_key 5436789765432456.000000

But it doesn't work either. Can somebody explain please, where I need to look, or what's wrong with my index/query?
In addition, I can't exactly call filters.customs.48467277, because Id may vary

The @ syntax in the full-text query searches Fields - not Attributes. Do you definitely have a Field called account_id_key ? Fields and Attributes are separate and processed seperately, can be filtered in different ways.
